# Type.GetType("ClassName") returns null

Tags: c#, types, get, null, .net-assembly

this works:

```
Type type = typeof(ClassName);
```

these four do not work, the type is null:

```
string classeName = "ClassName";
string classeNameWithNamenspace = "namespace.ClassName";
Assemly assembly = Assembly.Load("MyAssemblyName");

Type type = Type.GetType($"{ClassName}");
Type type = Type.GetType($"{classeNameWithNamenspace}");

Type type = Type.GetType($"{classeName}, {assembly.FullName}");
Type type = Type.GetType($"{classeNameWithNamenspace}, {assembly.FullName}");
```

Tested all the variants described above.
Checked that all names are spelled correctly.
Also checked with Debug.

I don't know what to do, it should actually work.

Comment: Have you tried using the output from `typeof(ClassName).AssemblyQualifiedName`?

Comment: yes i have tried ```var type = Type.GetType(nameof(ClassName));``` the same result.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this.  The first three return `null` (which is expected), but the fourth one returns the type.  The code shown doesn't compile, so this is definitely not a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: and if you don't want to specify the assembly: *start* from `assembly` instead: `assembly.GetType(classNameWithNamenspace)`

Comment: I try this: ```Type type = Type.GetType($"AssemblyName.ClassName");``` this works, but why do I have to write the AssemlyName again, as I have it in the using AssemlyName?

Comment: Because the class sits in an assembly. Once you realize that, it's obvious why you have to.

Comment: `Type.GetType` needs an assembly-qualified name, not just the name of the class (unless the type is part of mscorlib).

Comment: @Edlaos the assembly and namespace *do not have to match*; the mention of `AssemblyName.ClassName` is misleading, as that is actually `SomeNamespace.ClassName`, where `SomeNamespace` just happens to be the same as `AssemblyName` in your case (and in many cases), but the type loader *doesn't assume that*

Comment: thanks DavidG, David, Marc Gravell and MakePeaceGreatAgain. Have learned something from you and it's working now, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The types for all GetType() are returned by this code. What is it you want to achieve?

```
using System.Reflection;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string classeName = nameof(TestClass);
        var classeNameWithNamenspace = typeof(TestClass).AssemblyQualifiedName;
        //var assembly = Assembly.Load(classeNameWithNamenspace);

        Type? type1 = Type.GetType(classeName);
        Type? type2 = Type.GetType(classeNameWithNamenspace);

        //Type? type3 = Type.GetType($"{classeName}, {assembly.FullName}");
        //Type? type4 = Type.GetType($"{classeNameWithNamenspace}, {assembly.FullName}");
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
}
```